# Is it possible to query records from a nested json structure using blaze python

Tags: python, blaze

I am trying to use blaze for querying data from json. It is possible to query data if json is single level. When I am trying to give query for nested json the following error occurs : 
ValueError: Not understood

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.